# grep in large file includes lines that do not match the given pattern

Tags: grep

I have a large log file (28MB) that I'm trying to run some queries on. I've noticed any time I try to `grep` a particular minute in the file, the output overruns into the following minute before stopping.

```
>> grep 'T19:54' aws_elb.log | awk '{print $2}'
...
2021-06-10T19:54:59.934622Z
2021-06-10T19:54:59.938837Z
2021-06-10T19:54:59.946078Z
2021-06-10T19:54:59.957267Z
2021-06-10T19:54:59.965747Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.017838Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.017989Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.048256Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.057552Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.070085Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.073510Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.073589Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.084122Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.103200Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.106992Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.186963Z
2021-06-10T19:55:00.236496Z
```

I'm stumped. Is this an issue with the file size?

Comment: what's the output with just the `grep` and without the `awk`? And should we assume you want to match only on those timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will probably be a `T19:54` at another place in the line considering that you are printing just a section of it with awk.

Consider going the other way around:

```
awk '{print $2}' aws_elb.log | grep 'T19:54' -
```

Comment: or drop the `grep`: `awk '$2 ~ "T19:54" { print $2 }'` (or even `awk '{$0=$2} /T19:54/'`)

Comment: Great tips. I will learn about awk someday.